# Display array map in render

Tags: reactjs

Trying to display an array of images in my component, I get no errors just an empty div:

```
class StarRating extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { rating } = this.props;

        const ratings = [...Array(5)].map((item, i) => {
            let src = rating < i ? "star-filled" : "star-unfilled";
            <img
                style={styles.image}
                src={require(`../../../../assets/${src}.png`)}
            />;
        });

        return <div style={styles.container}>{ratings}</div>;
    }
}
```

How can I display my images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return inside your map.

```
class StarRating extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { rating } = this.props;

    const ratings = [...Array(5)].map((item, i) => {
      let src = rating < i ? 'star-filled' : 'star-unfilled';
      return (
        <img
          style={styles.image}
          src={require(`../../../../assets/${src}.png`)}
        />
      );
    });

    return <div style={styles.container}>{ratings}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return in the ratings declaration. If you use `{}`inside the `map` you need to state a return.

```
const ratings = [...Array(5)].map((item, i) => {
            let src = rating < i ? "star-filled" : "star-unfilled";
            return <img // add return
                style={styles.image}
                src={require(`../../../../assets/${src}.png`)}
            />;
        });
```

*Edit*. Added option without return:

```
const ratings = [...Array(5)].map((item, i) => 
            <img
                style={styles.image}
                src={require(`../../../../assets/${rating < i ? "star-filled" : "star-unfilled"}.png`)}
            />
        );
```